# How to include values with count 0?

Tags: sql, count

I have the following table called Trains.

```
id | name | train_id
 1   Carl      1
 2   Kat       1
 3   Paul      2
 4   Adam      4
 5   Janet     4
 6   James     4
```

I am trying to count for each name how many other people are in the same train.

Here's what I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT T1.name, COUNT(T2.name)
FROM Trains T1, Trains T2
WHERE T1.name<>T2.name AND T1.train_id=T2.train_id
GROUP BY T1.name;
```

However, the result I get is

```
Janet  2
Adam   2
Kat    1
Carl   1
James  2
```

but I should also have the name 'Paul' there with count 0. I am new to SQL and I am unsure of how I could change my code to have the zero values here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you phrase your current logic as a left join, it should work:

```sql
SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t2.name) AS cnt
FROM Trains t1
LEFT JOIN Trains t2
    ON t1.name <> t2.name AND t1.train_id = t2.train_id
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The problem with your current approach is that it doing an old school implicit inner join, not a left join.  This means that first the join happens, then the `WHERE` clause is filtering off the missing Paul record.  By using a left join, all names on the left side of the join are retained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `join` is needed.  Just use window functions:

```
select name, count(*) over (partition by train_id) - 1
from trains t;
```

Basically, `count(*) over (partition by train_id)` counts the number of rows on the train.  The `- 1` is to subtract the current row.

Answer (score 0):

We use COUNT(*) which counts all of the input rows for a group.

(COUNT() also works with expressions, but it has slightly different behavior.)

Here's how the database executes this query:

FROM train_id:  — First, retrieve all of the records from the Trains table.

GROUP BY name — Next, determine the unique name groups.

SELECT ... — Finally, select the name and the count of the number of rows in that group.

We also give this count of rows an alias using AS people_in_same_train to make the output more readable.

SELECT
name, COUNT(*) AS people_in_same_train
FROM Trains
GROUP BY name;